# Receiving TypeError in Azure Function with Python runtime

Tags: python, function, azure-functions, typeerror

I'm having trouble understanding the problem here.

- HTTP-triggered Azure Function
- Python runtime
- Testing on localhost with HTTPS (no problem here)
- URL:`https://localhost:5007/api/BARCODE_API`
- Goal: Check and validate the `type` parameter of the URL

  - Ensure it is present, a string, etc.

**This works:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    if req.params.get('type'):
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Test SUCCESS",
            status_code=200
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Test FAIL",
            status_code=400
        )
```

**I can't see why this does NOT work...**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: 

    def check_type():
        try:
            if req.params.get('type'):
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Test SUCCESS",
                    status_code=200
                )
        except:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Test FAIL",
                status_code=400
            )

    check_barcode = check_type()
```

- I also tried passing `req.params.get('type')` to the `check_type()` function, but same error..

**Error**

```
Exception: TypeError: unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported type "<class 'azure.functions.http.HttpResponseConverter'>" for Python type "NoneType"
```

I can't see why this is happening when I send `https://localhost:5007/api/BARCODE_API?type=ean13`

---

**EDIT 1:** Using @MohitC's recommended syntax still causes the error above.

- Test1 shows it failing with a Status 500 (crux of this question)
- Test2 shows it succeeding with a Status 200 then failing with a Status 400 (as it should)
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that if your `if req.params.get('type'):` is evaluating to false, then no exception is raised and your function returns `None` type, which is probably further causing the mentioned error.

There are couple of things you could do here,

1. Return the test fail status code in the else part of your code.
2. Raise an exception if the condition is not true, then the `except` part would return what you want.

```
    def check_type():
        try:
            if req.params.get('type'):
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Test SUCCESS",
                    status_code=200
                )
            else:
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Test FAIL",
                    status_code=400
                )
        except:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Test FAIL",
                status_code=400
            )
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on architecture of your Azure API shown elegantly in Gif's, it looks like your main function must return something. You are collecting the HTTP response in `check_barcode` but not returning it.

Try below code:

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: 

    def check_type():
        try:
            if req.params.get('type'):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            return False

    check_barcode = check_type()
    if check_barcode:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Test SUCCESS",
            status_code=200
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Test FAIL",
            status_code=400
        )
```

Comment: The weird thing is that I *am* sending the `type` parameter and the `if` is still evaluated to `None`. I sent `https://localhost:5007/api/BARCODE_API?type=ean13` to both examples in the original post. The first works, the second does not.

Comment: I captured this in **EDIT 1** above.

Comment: I added some logging and the `try: if` block is evaluating to `ean13` (AKA: Python is reading the `type` parameter from the URL). The failure happens on the `return func.HttpResponse("Test SUCCESS", status_code=200)`. This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @SeaDude updated with another answer, try it

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Your answer worked well for me.